# How to properly nest a for loop into a while loop in Python

Tags: python

So I am learning python and there is something that bothers me. For the chunk of sample code below:

```
print("Test")

while True:
    print("statement0")

    x = input()
    print(x)

    if x == 1:
        print("statement1")
        y += input()
        print(y)

    elif x == 2:
        print("statement2")
        y += input()
        print(y)
    elif x == 3:
        print("statement3")
        y += input()
        print(y)
    elif x == 4:
        print("statement4")
        break
```

The if statements don't seem to be able to execute. After the value of x is printed it will loop back to statement0.

Comment: `input()` returns a `str`, you should convert `x` to an `int` before comparing it to other `int`s or compare it to strings

Comment: In other words, something like `x == 1` can never be true in this code, at best it would be `x == '1'`, but you could also just `x = int(input())` (the difference is that in the latter case your script would end with an exception if the user enters something that's not a valid integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first specify what will be the data type of the variable x.

- Now as you are equating x to integers, you need to add `int` before the `input()` function.
- Also, you have not initialized the variable `y` before, so python will throw an error. Define `y` beforehand with any integer value.
- And try to keep the expressions inside parenthesis as it helps in easier understanding.

So, your final code becomes:

```
print("Test")

while True:
    print("statement0")

    x = int(input())
    print(x)

    y = 0  # initialize y with any value 

    if (x == 1):  # edit
        print("statement1")
        y += int(input())
        print(y)

    elif (x == 2):  # edit
        print("statement2")
        y += int(input())
        print(y)
    elif (x == 3):  # edit
        print("statement3")
        y += int(input())
        print(y)
    elif (x == 4):  # edit
        print("statement4")
        break
```

Comment: I would upvote this answer, but one of the features of python I like best, is its conciseness. Putting `()` around those trivial expressions is overkill - the expressions are perfectly clear without that. I bet you learned a C-like language that requires parentheses, before learning Python! If so, that's the real reason it looks "better" to you with the parentheses - Familiarity. So did I, but I don't miss those parentheses when programming in python. :) I use parentheses in more complex expressions, to make the parts clearer. But in this case, its simply clutter, with no benefit.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yeah you're right! They are much useful when there are complex expressions. I added those because they help make the code look cleaner and help visually organize the code in a logical way.

Answer (score 0):

While taking the input, use `x = int(input())`

And, also y is not defined in this case, before doing something like `y+=int(input())`, you have to declare y above like `y = 0`

Thank you!